# What is the difference between Skype Bot Framework and Microsoft Bot Framework? Does the former present any advantages?

Tags: botframework, skype-bots

From what I could understand, **Microsoft Bot Framework** appears to be a superset of **Skype Bot Framework**. As in, you can develop Bot Applications using MS Bot Framework with Skype as the client. So where does the difference lie?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now the Skype Bot API exposes additional functionality of Skype (such as audio) that aren't included in the Bot Framework.  You can use either one though to build a text/images only Skype bot.

Under the covers, the Bot Framework uses the Skype Bot Framework SDK just as you might if you coded to it directly.